# How to intentionally crash MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

the goal is simple, but rather unusual. I wrote a database auto-repair script (as one of the tables keeps crashing from time to time, probably due to very large amounts being inserted and deleted constantly), and I want to test it. The problem is, that I need to crash a table on purpose, and I have no idea how. Any suggestions?

Comment: does it go something like this: ALTER TABLE <tabname> ENGINE=InnoDB; ?

Comment: Write some time consuming UPDATE SQL and press reset button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can certainly make a MyISAM table look crashed by truncating the .MYI file to 4k (Assuming it was bigger than 4k). Then do a FLUSH TABLE, followed by a query which needs to use an index.

If the tables are crashing spontaneously, then either

- There is a bug in the server
  OR
- Something bad is happening - either someone kill -9 the server, it crashes, the power fails, or someone is modifying the MyISAM files

MyISAM tables should not crash spontaneously, but you can expect them to crash following an unclean shutdown. Unclean shutdowns should not happen very often, if they are, it is an operational problem. Ask your operations engineers what's going on. It is normally clear what's happened from reviewing the mysql server error log.

Comment: I used `truncate -s <bytes> <table>.MYI` and then `flush table <table>`, but table didn't crash.  `kill -9` worked.

Comment: kill -9 failed. kill -11 failed. even while adding massive records. truncating MYI failed! but truncating MYD by reducing it a few K PLUS mysqlcheck (without repair) worked. `truncate -s 20003764 call_log_archiveX.MYD` then `mysqlcheck dbname -uXXXX -pXXXX` even though it still took a few seconds for "crashed" to be populated. But it did register the table as crashed successfully. `show table status where comment like '%crashed%'`

Answer (score 7):

In MyIsam, run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` and kill it while it runs. The table will be marked as crashed.